# Does python 3.10 support gunicorn?

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am trying to build a python 3.10 image for my application and want to use gunicorn. As per the official document its only supported till 3.9 version.

[Gunicorn document](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/)

I tried to install gunicorn on a debain python image but the app exists without any error. Is this due to the reason that gunicorn is not compatible ? But with 3.9 python image everything seems to work as expected.

I have installed gunicorn using the below command

```
RUN apt-get -y install gunicorn
```

Is there some way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works. Try installing it using "pip install gunicorn", this is how I installed it, and it will likely take into account which python version you have installed.

Source: I run gunicorn with python 3.10.6

Comment: so i must just run `RUN pip install gunicorn` ?

Comment: "pip install gunicorn" is the command I used. I run Pop! os, which works similar to Ubuntu. I am not sure what your system or setup uses, but I encourage you to try a few commands. At the very least, the problem isn't a compatibility issue between python 3.10.x and gunicorn

Comment: tried what you said but still it exists without any error. Do you know how i could troubleshoot more? it has no logs and inspect is also not useful

Comment: [official docs say python 3.5 or greater](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html?highlight=Requirements:%20Python#installation). the little image on pypi must be out of date, because 3.5 and 3.6 are already EOL